# Create Excel Hyperlinks which include data from cells B2-B10000 (or so)

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I'm learning mandarin Chinese and study from an excel file with over 10,000 vocabulary words.  To view example sentences easily, I want to place my own 10,000 hyperlinks to http://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word=%E4%B8%80, except replace the content after "?word=" with each of the 10,000 characters in rows B2-B10002.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Entering the formula `=HYPERLINK(B2;RIGHT(B2;LEN(B2)-FIND("=";B2)))` into `C2` and copying it down to `C10002` would do the trick for you.

Now if you want the URL entities to be decoded you will need to apply perhaps another function to the part `RIGHT(B1;LEN(B1)-FIND("=";B1))` but as far as I know there is no such thing in Excel

Comment: You could take a look at this one for URL functions http://www.icrossing.com/uk/ideas/url-tools-addin-excel_5458. I hope it works for mandarin

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ZcP.jpg)

Type this in C2

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word="&ENCODEURL(B2))
```

This Formuala will encode the content of B2 to make sure it's URL friendly using "ENCODEURL" Available in Excel 2013 or later

Assuming B2 = "Value 1" this cell (C2) will be

```
http://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word=Value%201
```

Copy this cell and paste it on you 1000+ cells and it'll automatically adjust the row number

---

For **older Versions** of Excel You can use

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word="&(B2))
```

and if it doesn't work (your browser doesn't auto encode) you might have to encode the text your self using any tool that support multiline encoding e.g. [Text Fixer](http://www.textfixer.com/html/encode-url.php)

paste the encoded text in your worksheet and adjust the formula to point to it, just edit the **(B2)** part

Comment: It's good practise to include a sentence noting that the function your formula is relying upon (e.g. [ENCODEURL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ENCODEURL-function-07C7FB90-7C60-4BFF-8687-FAC50FE33D0E)) is only available in versions of Excel >= xl2013 or Excel Online. Without including a remark about the version limitations, users may get confused and frustrated attempting your solution on previous versions.

Comment: I edited it.
it might not be needed in first place after testing I fount that my browser automatically encode links. but just in case I included a way for encoding outside of excel, Thank you for the remark.